# Using a laptop as WiFi hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, router, laptop, hotspot

In our house, we have one wired Internet connection and need to share it among multiple computers.

Does using a laptop as a WiFi router have any bad effects on the laptop's WiFi adapter?

Answer (score 2):

No, running an Ad-hoc WiFi hotspot from your laptop WiFi adapter should cause no problems. It's normal traffic, the same as downloading a lot directly. A standard WiFi adapter is designed to run in Ad-hoc mode.

Comment: I can see this working where the Internet is coming in over ethernet or USB or something, but surely if the Internet is being supplied TO THE LAPTOP over Wifi, then this will break, IE A Laptop can't be both Ad-Hoc and structured (I assume this to be the case, I don't think I've ever used ad-hoc networking)

Comment: @davidgo nothing prevents a laptop from having two wifi modules or usb sticks, or from using (rare sure) modules that allow two connections from a single radio.

Comment: Agreed, however the question implies a single WIFI connection.  I suspect a an ad-hoc and structured connection from a radio would be out of the range of a Superuser question as I doubt there is off-the-shelf software to do this.

Comment: @davidgo it would be implemented on the radio chip. Windows has APIs for it though individual drivers would need to support it. On routers, DD-WRT and Open-WRT and Tomato and every off the shelf 3rd party firmware support it if the chipset does. But as for as the question goes, **I'm 99% sure it implies ethernet to wifi bridging.**

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Ad-Hoc.

Comment: Then how would someone use a laptop as a "wifi router"